# JavaScript event listener when registered second time doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two js function as given below the function `nextPage` is working fine but the `previousPage` function when called the event `webkitAnimationEnd` doesn't work as desired.
Link to jsfiddle:[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8Tuy/24/).

```
var currentPage = 0;
    function nextPage()
    {   
        alert(currentPage);
        var pages   = document.getElementsByClassName('pages');
        pages[currentPage].className = "pages pageanim";
        pages[currentPage].addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
        this.style.left     = '0%';
        this.style.zIndex   = currentPage;
        currentPage = currentPage+1;
    }, false);

}

    function previousPage()
    {   
        //alert(currentPage);
        var pages   = document.getElementsByClassName('pages pageanim');
        pages[0].className = "pages revpageanim";
    
        pages[0].addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
        this.style.left     = '49%';
        this.style.zIndex   = currentPage+1;
        currentPage = currentPage-1;
    }, false);
    }
```

Here is my html:

```
  <body onLoad="applyZindex();">
   <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
  <header><button class="nav left" onClick="previousPage();">&lt;&lt;prev</button>
<h3 class="left">Previewer (TM)
</h3><button class="nav right" onClick="nextPage();">
next>></button></header>
            <section style=" position:relative;">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="page1" title="page1" class="pages" />
            <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="page2" title="page2" class="pages" />
            <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="page1" title="page1" class="pages" />
            <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="page2" title="page2" class="pages"  />
            </section>
            <footer></footer>
        </body>
```

Comment: Can you http://jsfiddle.net/ this?

Comment: i cant use it now ,can u tell me why when i  call pages[0].addEventListener in previousPage function event listner of nextPage is working instead.

Comment: shall i paste my html and css tooo??

Comment: html is necessary, css not. P.S. i meant for jsfiddle (:

Comment: @ArunKillu, can you complete http://jsfiddle.net/K8Tuy/ this(adding css and else)?

Comment: @ted css added, but what about image but image can u check.http://jsfiddle.net/K8Tuy/2/

Comment: @ArunKillu, you may put some images (example: http://jsfiddle.net/K8Tuy/4/). Just try to make everything work in jsfiddle like it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/K8Tuy/28/ here you go;

So, you need to `removeEventListener` on every click if you  also `addEventListener` on every click;
Generally, its not a good idea to `addEventListener` on every click. It should be initialize once and your logic should be inside the buttons.

```
var currentPage = 0;
    function nextPage()
    {   
        var pages   = document.getElementsByClassName('pages');
        pages[currentPage].className = "pages pageanim";
        pages[currentPage].addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
            this.style.left     = '0%';
            this.style.zIndex   = currentPage;
            pages[currentPage].className = "pages";
            currentPage = currentPage+1;
            this.removeEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd',arguments.callee,false);
            console.log(currentPage);
        }, false);

}

    function previousPage()
    {   
        //alert(currentPage);
        var pages   = document.getElementsByClassName('pages');
        page = pages[currentPage-1];
        page.className = "pages revpageanim";

        page.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
            currentPage = currentPage-1;
            this.style.left     = '49%';
            page.style.zIndex   = pages.length-currentPage;
            page.className = "pages";
            this.removeEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd',arguments.callee,false);
            console.log(currentPage);
        }, false);
    }​
```

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/K8Tuy/35/ -- `arguments.callee` replaced with "function name"

Comment: this.removeEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd',arguments.callee,false);is not working in my browser.i tnk it dosent work in strict mode